# what might be the error causing while running the program

Tags: python, module, storyboard, coordinates, importerror

i have installed storyboard by following commands

sudo apt update
pip install story board

but in my program there is a line which causes error that is

from storyboard import Coord
ImportError: cannot import name Coord

after this i try to install coordinates with the command

pip install coordinates

But it gave this error

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coordinates (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for coordinates

can any help me or suggest what should be done ??

Answer (score 0):

This package might not be available for older pip, try updating pip and then installing it.

Refer to this link for other reasons: [Fix the pip error: Couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2017/04/fix-the-pip-error-couldnt-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement/)